# VSCode - Missing Plug Icon from CLI Extension

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, cli

A coworker of mine is missing his plug icon that's made available through the Salesforce CLI Integration (installed via salesforce extension pack). After going through the status bar options, trying a window reload, and even uninstall and reinstalling the pack/vscode I could not get it to pop up. Below is a picture with what I'm talking about.[image: Description]

Comment: To further clarify, right clicking the status bar on his computer doesn't give us the option to enable "Salesforce CLI Integration (Extended)" like it does on mine, even with identical extensions installed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is [Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm) installed properly. Check by typing sfdx in the terminal.